# Name of closing button on Windows Forms

Tags: winforms

What's the name of the default red button with an X in the middle at the top right?

EDIT: I want to get the event associated with clicking that button.

Comment: Why are you asking? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was looking for it in the properties so that I could disable it, and realized I didn't know its name.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean delete. I want to get the event associated with clicking that button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot disable the close box on its own using in properties window like you can with the minimize and maximize boxes. You can however disable the control box which contains them all.

[image]

Setting `ControlBox` to false will remove the minimize, maximize and close buttons.

You might want to consider *why* you are doing this though, as it's generally a good idea to let users quit out of windows using the close button (think of it as a cancel button).

---

**EDIT:**

You can handle when the user clicks on that close button using either the [`Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) or the [`Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx) events of the `Form`. The difference between the two is that the `Closing` event fires before the form has closed (meaning that you can veto the closure by setting the [`Cancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) property of the `FormClosingEventArgs` to `true`), whereas the `Closed` event fires after the form has actually closed.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to hook all messages  goes to a form by implementing ImessageFilter interface
this link can be use full [Using IMessageFilter to create a generic filter for operating system events](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/imessagefilterarticle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by setting the ControlBox to false in the form properties, or in code like the following:

```
this.ControlBox = false;
```

Setting this will also hide the minimize and maximize buttons if that is OK.  If not, the solution is a bit more elaborate.